# The value of int a

Tags: c, int

I don't understand why 'a' shows 23 on screen when I run it. Can anyone give me an explanation? Thanks in advance.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int a = 027;
    printf("%d",a); //23

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nicely written question, so have an upvote: there's certainly a duplicate out there, but without knowing the search terms, it would be difficult to find.

Comment: ... `2*8^1 + 7*8^0 = 16 + 7 = 23`

Comment: @Bathsheba There's a canonical dupe in the C wiki FAQ. https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info

Answer (score 2):

Integer constants that start with `0` are in **octal** representation.  This means each digit represents a multiple of a power of 8, and the power of 8 associated with each digit starts at 0 for the rightmost digit and increases as you move to the left.

In the case of `027`, its value is 2*8<sup>1</sup> + 7*8<sup>0</sup> == 2*8 + 7 == 16 + 7 == 23

Comment: Each **position** is associated with a power of eight. Each **digit** denotes a multiple of the power of eight for its position. The digit does not represent a power of eight. For example, in `027`, `2` denotes 16, which is not a power of eight, and `7` denotes seven, which is not a power of eight. Remember, **you** know what you mean, but people who are just learning do not—they do not have the information needed to figure out the non-literal meaning of your words. Telling them that something represents a thing it does not could be confusing.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Good catch, as always.  Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You initialized a with the value `027` integer numbers with a leading `0` is how you represent octal numbers in C, you can use `0x` before a number if you want to have the number in hexadecimal representation. 
In the `printf` function you used `%d` which is used for displaying decimal numbers and it automatically converted `027` to decimal which is `23`, if you want to display the number in octal use `%o`.

Answer (score 1):

The preceding `0` actually refers to `octal`.

Similarly, we can specify hexadecimal as well by `0x`

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int a = 0xA;
    int b = 027;
    printf("%d\n", a);
    printf("%d\n", b);
    return 0;
}
```

would give:

```
10
23
```

Also, take note `0.something` is not `octal` but a `decimal`.